# Not able to get the data from Firebase database - it returns a null value

Tags: android, database, firebase, null, return

I am trying to retrieve the data from Firebase:

```
 DatabaseReference customerRef = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("Drivers").child(driverId).child("customerRideId");
 Log.d("TAG_SiX",customerRef.toString());

 customerRef.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
     @Override
     public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
        // retriveCustomerID(dataSnapshot);
         Log.d("TAG_eight",dataSnapshot.toString());
         Map<String,String> map = 
           (Map<String,String>)dataSnapshot.getValue();

     }

     @Override
     public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

     }
 });
```

Here is the logcat value

```
D/TAg_five: DataSnapshot { key = customerRideId, value = null }
```

05

Here is the Firebase data structure, I want the value of `customerRideId` which in logcat shows null and the customerRideId is in the DriverID.

```
Drivers
    PyltxOLXcWfZf6itgJEMWC4ylDu2
           driverEmail: "nishant@gmail.com"
           driverName: "Nishant"
    customerRideId: "Sqpb6RFNhMOSiXeCrYj83aeeG7r2"
```

I want to retrieve the value of `customerRideId` but in logcat it shows null value please help me out in this.

```
here is the database screenshot
```

[DataBase Screen shot here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0GUwn.png)

Answer (score 0):

make sure you have added appropriate dependencies in gradle and there is some data in firebase DB
If all those things are good, try:

```
private FirebaseDatabase database;
```

In your method:

```
database=FirebaseDatabase.getInstance();
DatabaseReference customerRef = database.getReference("Drivers/"+driverId+"/customerRideId");
```

Comment: its still geving the null value

Answer (score 0):

Try this code ..

```
        DatabaseReference customerRef = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference();
    Query query1=customerRef.child("Drivers").child(customerRef.getKey()).child("customerRideId");
    Log.d("TAG_SiX", customerRef.toString());
    query1.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
            // retriveCustomerID(dataSnapshot);
            Log.d("TAG_eight", dataSnapshot.toString());
            Map<String, String> map =
                    (Map<String, String>) dataSnapshot.getValue();

        }

        @Override
        public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

        }
    });
```

Comment: But there is no difference in your code and my code

Answer (score 0):

To get the value of your `customerRideId` property, please use the following code:

```
DatabaseReference rootRef = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference();
DatabaseReference driverIdRef = rootRef.child("Drivers");
ValueEventListener valueEventListener = new ValueEventListener() {
    @Override
    public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
        String customerRideId = dataSnapshot.child("customerRideId").getValue(String.class);
        Log.d("TAG", customerRideId);
    }

    @Override
    public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {}
};
driverIdRef.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(valueEventListener);
```

The output will be: `Sqpb6RFNhMOSiXeCrYj83aeeG7r2`.

Comment: Not Working Alex Mamo still the value is null

Comment: In this case, please edit your question by adding the real database structure (a screenshot would be enough) and the code that you are using for getting the data, to see more clearly where the problem is.

Comment: i have added the screen shot plz check it out

Comment: It's more clear now. Please see my updated answer, just removed a `child()` method call. Does it work?